# User is not define when I sent POST request to /api/users/login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to sent post request to mLab Database to check if user have already account or not Server Response User is not Define. Check my code

```
// @route post api/user/login#

router.post('/login',(req,resp)=>{
  const email=req.body.email;
  const password=req.body.password;

// find user

  user.findOne({email})

     .then(user => {

  if(!user){

    return resp.status(404).json({email: "User not found  "})
   }


 // check password 

 bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)
  .then(isMatch=>{

     if(isMatch){

   resp.json({msg:'sucess'})

   }else{

   return resp.status(400).json({password:'password incorrect'});

 }});
 });

 });
```

Post Request to Server

```
http://localhost:5000/api/users/login

Key              Value

email          MyEmail@gmail.com

Password        MyPassword
```

Response from Server

```
ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

Comment: Have you imported the user model?

Comment: const User=require('../../models/User');

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`user.findOne({email})` should be `User.findOne({email})`. user with a capital U

Comment: thanks that was exactly my issues

Comment: @Haseeb-Shinwari glad it worked :) can you please mark this as answer?